# What does "your faith is built as you pray to God" mean?

Tags: meaning, conjunctions

Does "your faith is built as you pray to God" mean the same as your faith is built anytime you pray to God?

Comment: Hello Jimi,  please add the source of this quote to your question,.

Comment: "Does it mean the same?" It might, but it's what's known as an 'inspirational message' it's not meant to be taken absolutely literally. Consider, "Your wall is built as you add bricks" which is more clearly definable - add no bricks, build no wall.

Answer (score 2):

"as" has several senses.  The main sense here is "at the same time".  You pray and, at the same time, your faith builds.  A secondary sense is "because". Because you pray, your faith builds.

These two events are linked both in time, and one is the cause of the other.

Comment: Great answer. Does it mean every time you pray, your faith builds?

Comment: Please read my answer.  It explains what it means.  If you need to clarify your question please edit your question.